# I would like to know how to import data into the app by modifying this lambda code

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, translate

```
 import boto3 

 import json
 

 s3 = boto3.client('s3')


 def lambda_handler(event, context):

     bucket = "cloud-translate-output"
     key = "key value"
    
     try:
         data = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
         json_data = data["Body"].read()
 
         return{
             "response_code" : 200,
             "data": str(json_data)
         }
     except Exception as e:
         print (e)
         raise e
```

I'm making ios app with xcode.
And I want to use aws to bring data from s3 to app in order of app-api gateway-lambda-s3. But is there a way to use the data of api using api in app, and if I upload this data to bucket number 1 of s3, the cloudformation will translate the uploaded text file and automatically save it to bucket number 2, and I want to import the text data file stored in bucket number 2 back to app through lambda, not key value, is there a way to use only the name of the bucket?

Answer (score 0):

> if I upload this data to bucket number 1 of s3, the cloudformation will translate the uploaded text file and automatically save it to bucket number 2

Sadly, this is not how CloudFormation work. It can't read or translate automatically any files from buckets, or upload them to new buckets.

I would stick with a lambda function. It is more suited to such tasks.

Comment: I implemented this way using cloudformation. When I upload a text file to Bucket1, the file that translated the text file is saved to Bucket2. I found this method on Google.